# Como pegar todos os elementos da <ul> utilizando o document.querySelectorAll() - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

- Quero pegar essas **li** dentro da **ul** usando o document.querySelectorAll()

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei desse jeito , mas não veio o NodeList das **li** , só apareceu a **ul**

```
    function TrocaLataPrincipal(){
    let pepsiPrincipal = document.querySelector(".pepsi")
    let lataPepsi = document.querySelectorAll(".latasDeRefri")
    console.log(lataPepsi)
}

TrocaLataPrincipal()
```

- Resultado no console

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você busca por `.latasDeRefri`, está trazendo somente o elemento que possui a classe "latasDeRefri", que no caso é o `ul`.

Se quer todas as `li` dentro dele, basta incluir isso no seletor:

```js
let latasPepsi = document.querySelectorAll(".latasDeRefri li");
//                                                   aqui ^^
for (const li of latasPepsi)
    console.log(li);
```

```html
<ul class="latasDeRefri">
  <li>pepsi 1</li>
  <li>pepsi 2</li>
  <li>pepsi 3</li>
</ul>
```

Outra alternativa é fazer a busca por `li` a partir da `ul`:

```js
// busca o primeiro ul com a classe latasDeRefri
let ul = document.querySelector(".latasDeRefri");
// busca os "li" dentro do ul
for (const li of ul.querySelectorAll('li'))
    console.log(li);
```

```html
<ul class="latasDeRefri">
  <li>pepsi 1</li>
  <li>pepsi 2</li>
  <li>pepsi 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>outro</li>
</ul>
```

Note que agora fiz a busca por "li" a partir do `ul` encontrado (e não a partir do `document`). Assim, ele só busca o que está dentro do `ul` (se eu fizesse a busca no `document`, ele também encontraria o `<li>outro</li>`).

---

Leia a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) para mais informações sobre os seletores.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, hkotsubo  :)

Answer (score 2):

Você está pegando somente a UL, então precisa selecionar as LI dentro do UL:

```
function TrocaLataPrincipal(){
    const pepsiPrincipal = document.querySelector(".pepsi")
    const lataPepsi = document.querySelectorAll(".latasDeRefri li")
    console.log(lataPepsi)
}

TrocaLataPrincipal()
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Marcos :)